# How to add custom icon in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, xhtml, twitter-bootstrap

I'm adding icon with Twitter Bootstrap without problem. They have a lot of alternatives.

> http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons

However, I couldn't find appropriate icon for one of menu item. It is about "car".
What I want is I would like to add my custom icon. How can I do this?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can create your own icon by defining it in your own class like s:

```
.icon-car {
    background-image: url("http://cdn5.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Symbolicons_Transportation/24/Car.png");
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Keeping in mind of course to use the prefix `.icon-*` since it is targetted by an attribute selector set by the bootstrap to apply all styles (widh/height/line-height etc...).

Just try to keep to the same width and height as the original icons (14x14), this way you won't have to define your own width and height and it won't mess with the `line-height` of your elements. Here is a demo with such a case: http://jsfiddle.net/RwFeu/

Comment: @SNaRe yes, that is because the icon you introduce is not available under the `.icon-white` sprite sheet, that is a separate sheet with white icons.

Comment: @SNaRe [white icons sheet](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png), [black icons sheet](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/img/glyphicons-halflings.png).

Comment: In this case what do you suggest me to do? I changed the color with photoshop to white. However, now it looks weird though.

Comment: @SNaRe you need to find your own icons to use, the one i used is from: http://iconfinder.com , though you can find some more in sites like: http://glyphicons.com/, http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/ or somewhere else.

Comment: I mean, I want to change the color to the white. I changed with photoshop black to white but it doesn't show properly. Problem is not finding icon, I already have. Problem is making it white.

Comment: @SNaRe oh, thats a subject for a whole 'nother question :P ..but in photoshop you can just invert the colors through "image > Adjustments > Invert", that should flip the colors, and of course save it in its original format, which should be saved for web and devices in PNG-24 format with transparency.

Comment: The jsfiddle link doesn't work anymore, I notice the image link on iconfinder.com is broken. If I change the jsfiddle to use another link (to an image that exists) it still doesn't work.

Comment: I agree with Max, this doesn't seem to work anymore :(

Answer (score 14):

Here's what we do, so that all the icons are in a single sprite file and you can allow arbitrary sized icons.

create a CSS file like

```
[class^="icon-custom-"],
[class*=" icon-custom-"] {
  background-image: url("https://app.10000ft.com/images/compSpritesButtonsIcons.png?8");
}

.icon-custom-logo { background-position : -530px -700px; width : 142px; height : 158px;  }
.icon-custom-intheoffice { background-position: -395px -60px; width: 24px; height: 24px  }
```

And then in your markup,

```
<i class="icon-search"></i> a standard bootstrap icon
<i class="icon-custom-intheoffice"></i> a custom icon, using our own sprite file.
<i class="icon-custom-logo"></i> a logo, an even bigger sprite icon
<!-- spritefile from www.10000ft.com. not for reuse, please -->
```

Note that this assumes a single sprites file that contains all the icons. If you have multiple sprite files, the `background-image` needs to be set for each icon, accordingly.

JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/shyamh/cvHdt/

This solution is based on the example posted by [Kevin](http://favbulous.com/post/1006/create-custom-icons-for-twitter-bootstrap-easily)