# fixing padding for custom icon using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, icons, padding

I had the same question as the question  [How to add custom icon in Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393325/how-to-add-custom-icon-in-twitter-bootstrap)

The solution for [How to add custom icon in Twitter Bootstrap](http://jsfiddle.net/RwFeu/) from the answer for the question above looks great. The only thing I want to ask is how to set up 20px between the icon to the left and 30px icon to the right. The icon I use is not a standard 14x14 pxpx, so again I used [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/RwFeu/).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add padding to the custom class you have created, like so:

**CSS**

```
.icon-car {
    background-image: url("http://cdn5.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Symbolicons_Transportation/24/Car.png");
    background-position: center center;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:30px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RwFeu/7/