# Custom icon twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've already found this post
[How to add custom icon in Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393325/how-to-add-custom-icon-in-twitter-bootstrap)
But applying that solution it still computes me a 0x0px icon, I still can't understand how that may be possible but here's my sample code:
**HTML**

```
<i class="icon-linkedin"></i>
```

**CSS**

```
.icon-linkedin {
    background-image: url("../../resources/img/icon-linkedins.png");
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 3.0.0, I'm beginning to discover it ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't made one in bootstrap in a while, but it looks like the syntax might be a bit different now than it was when that post was made. This is how you generally would use an icon font with an element (or rather, a pseudo-element) with *ANY* icon font.

```
/* this just imports the font */
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=fontawesome);
.icon-linkedin:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome', sans-serif;
    content: "\f0e1"; 

}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kDQ3p/1/)**