# How to modify bootstrap icons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im' actualy learning how to use Bootstrap 3.3.7 and I would like to know how to modify/change the icons it provides. I would like to add new ones and I tried [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393325/how-to-add-custom-icon-in-twitter-bootstrap#10396873):

```
.icon-car {
  background-image: url("http://cdn5.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Symbolicons_Transportation/24/Car.png");
  background-position: center center;
}
```

> Keeping in mind of course to use the prefix .icon-* since it is targetted by an attribute selector set by the bootstrap to apply all styles (widh/height/line-height etc...).
>
> Just try to keep to the same width and height as the original icons (14x14), this way you won't have to define your own width and height and it won't mess with the line-height of your elements. Here is a demo with such a case: http://jsfiddle.net/RwFeu/

But it didn't work for me. Even if I change the URL (which doesn't work anymore) I don't have the possibility to use new icons.  This message I quoted is from 2012 and I'm wondering if there is a new way to achieve this?

Have a nice day =)

Comment: Do you want to add new icon, or do you want to change the existing Bootstrap icon shape?

Comment: There aren't any classes for `icons` starting with `icon` all icon classes in Bootstrap are called `glyphicons` and start with `glyphicons`.

Comment: Hi, I would like to use new icons.
And I thought not all icons were called by glyphicon, for example the font-awesomes icons (fa fa-*).